# Read a JSON Array from PHP in a jQuery Function

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2722709/723007) to help me build an HTML select menu from a JSON array using jQuery.

My JSON array is passed from a PHP script as $menu and looks like this:

```
{ "options": [
    { "id":"7","name":"Smith, John"},
    { "id":"4","name":"Jones, Tom"}
  ]
}
```

First I build the skeleton of my select menu and insert it into the page:

```
var div = '<div class="row">';
var label = '<label for="employee">Employee</label>';
var select = '<select name="employee id="employee">';
var close = '</select></div>';
var menu = div + label + select + close;

$('#clicked_link').prepend(menu);
```

Then I try to pass the $menu array to jQuery like this:

```
var json = '<?php echo $menu; ?>';
```

Then I try to append the options to the newly created select menu, using the example from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2722709/723007):

```
var options = eval('(' + json + ')');
var length = options.length;

for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
{
    var newOption = $('<option/>');
    newOption.attr('id', options[j].id);
    newOption.attr('name', options[h].name);
    $('#employee').append(newOption);
}
```

The select menu is showing up as expected, but it contains no options. Can anyone see where I'm making my error(s)? Thanks in advance.

**Revised to incorporate Rocket's solution:**

```
var json = <?php echo $menu; ?>;

var options = json.options;
var length = options.length;

for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
{
    var newOption = $('<option/>');
    newOption.attr('value', options[j].id);
    newOption.attr('text', options[j].name);
    $('#employee').append(newOption);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use `eval`, or even `JSON.parse` here.  JSON is valid JavaScript code.  You can just do this:

```
var json = <?php echo $menu; ?>;  // Note: the quotes have been removed.
```

This would make the following code:

```
var json = { "options": [
    { "id":"7","name":"Smith, John"},
    { "id":"4","name":"Jones, Tom"}
  ]
};
```

which, as you can see, is valid JavaScript code.

Then you can do `var options = json.options`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've implemented your solution, but am getting the same result (an empty select menu). I've posted the updated version in my quesiton. Am I also doing something wrong in my loop perhaps?

Comment: @cantera25: In your loop, you have `options[h].list`.  What is `h`?  Also, your `options` objects, don't have a `list` property.

Comment: Got it - the [h] was a typo in the accepted answer in the linked question, and I just assumed it was correct. I'll go edit that now. Changing it to [j] and switching to "text" and "value" within the loop did the trick. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 2):

why not

```
 var options = JSON.parse(json).options;
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Rocket's answer, and I believe there's also a bug in your loop. The line

`newOption.attr('name', options[h].list);`

`h` isn't defined. You probably want `j` instead. And the `name` attribute isn't meaningful on an `option`. For the value that will be displayed, set `text`. For the value that will be sent to the server when the form is submitted, set `value`.